# Open a book in iBooks reader

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme, ibooks

I'm trying to open an iBook via my iPhone app using this code :

```
- (void)goToiBookStore {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-books://itunes.apple.com/us/book/le-secret-du-poids/id711921224"];
    //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-bookss://itunes.apple.com/us/book/le-secret-du-poids/id711921224"]; // Also tried
    //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/le-secret-du-poids/id711921224?l=fr&ls=1"]; // Also tried

    // On teste si iBook installed
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
    else {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iBooks" message:NSLocalizedString(@"installer ibooks lab", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"annuler", nil) otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"installer", nil), nil] show];
    }
}
```

But, the URL does not send me to the iBook in iBooks but to the download page, is it normal ?

http://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_953506photo.png

Comment: Pretty normal, what if the book is charged? do you expect to be opened in iBook that easy? that url redirect obviously to the apple store for download/purchase.

Comment: I already bought and charged the book. Is there an URL to access directly to the book ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open iBooks, or open the store for that product, but not open a book directly.

If you want to open iBooks:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"ibooks://";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

UPDATE 2019:
You can open iBooks to a specific book now by including the assetid of the book you want to open. Example:

```
ibooks://assetid/1396541327
```

Details available on the Apple.com website - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202929

Comment: And how to specify the iBook I want to open ?

Comment: I tried "ibooks://itunes.apple.com/us/book/le-secret-du-poids/id711921224" but it's the same :/

Comment: Is not possible, you can either open iBooks or open the store, it's on my first message

Comment: Seb - if you have that book in your iBooks, you should be able to open it with the following link: 

ibooks://assetid/711921224 

This works for me with a title that I have already purchased from the Apple Store.